# xml-rpc or json-rpc with qml

Tags: qt, qml, xml-rpc, json-rpc

I'm trying to use xml-rpc or json-rpc with qml, but I cannot find a good way to start, most of the libraries in c++ are either old or cannot be built by msvc compiler.Any one who had an experience with rpc in qml please give me some good hints.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use in-built JSON.parse and JSON.stringify?

Comment: sk2212: is there any example how to communicate with a server using what you have mentioned.I'm trying to make RPC communication it's not just about JSON.

Comment: You just talked about json where is the rpc part?

Comment: qjsonrpc: https://bitbucket.org/devonit/qjsonrpc

Comment: Thank you, that would make the job.